# All combinations choosing 3 items each from 4 unique bags

Tags: r, combinatorics

Trying to do something like expand.grid in R, but as if expand.grid  created all combinations of sets of 3 from each factor/group.

(E.G.)...

`V1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
V2 <- c(A,B,C,D,E,F)
V3 <- c(Red, Green, Blue)`

Now pull three "items" from each vector:

`Combination 1 = (1,2,3;A,B,C;Red, Green , Blue)
Combination 2 = (1,2,4;A,B,C;Red, Green , Blue)
Combination 3 = (1,2,5;A,B,C;Red, Green , Blue)`..........

........And so on.

Because there are only 3 items in V3 it stays the same the whole time, and the order is not of concern (i.e. we don't care about the difference between (Red, Blue, Green) and (Green, Red, Blue))``

So I guess because V3 is "constant" through-out all combinations that it really boils down to combinations between V1 and V2.

In conclusion: Basically I need to expand.grid for every combination, of sets of 3 from each vector, without order mattering in the set of 3 (ABC and CBA are the same).

Thanks

Comment: Hi : I don't know if there's something in R for doing this but expand.grid won't do it. Given what you want to do, there are (6 choose 3) possible elements for combo 1 and combo 2 which means 20 different possible elements for each of them.  So, you've got 20 times 20 = 400 possible elements ( combo 3 is fixed so it can be ignored ) in your final result . As I said, not sure if there's an R function for this but maybe this helps a little.

Comment: Hi: I didn't look at it carefully but this looks helpful as far as what's available in R. https://davetang.org/muse/2013/09/09/combinations-and-permutations-in-r/